# Using variables from one Octave function file in another

Tags: scope, octave

Say I have two Octave function files in the same load path: file1.m and file2.m.

file1:

```
function [variable] = file1()
    variable = 1;
endfunction
```

file2:

```
function file2()
    variable2 = variable*2;
endfunction
```

How can I make it so that I can use `variable` in file2?

I have tried many things, such as:

1.

```
function [variable] = file1()
    global variable = 1;
endfunction

function file2()
    global variable;
    variable2 = variable*2;
endfunction
```

---

2.

Calling file1() before or within file2() in file2.m

```
file1();
function file2()
    global variable;
    variable2 = variable*2;
endfunction
```

---

3.

Using variable as a parameter when calling file2()

```
function file2(variable)
    variable2 = variable*2;
endfunction
```

---

with no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean "no success." What happened? How are you testing? Edit your question provide any error messages.

Comment: At least in Matlab, this line would be invalid and the Editor would warn you about it: `global variable = 1;`. You can declare a variable `global` and set it's value on the same line. I also don't think you're allowed to pass a global variable as an output argument (kind of defeats the purpose). I only use Matlab so I really can't test how this works in octave.

Comment: @horchler he's using Octave and that's valid syntax there. It allows you to use an initialization value for static (persistent) and global variables like other saner languages.

Comment: @horchler in my actual program I am trying to get a vector from one file to the other, but I get an index error as in file2 the vector is empty.

Comment: @JonathanO'Farrell: See [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Multiple-Return-Values.html#Multiple-Return-Values) from the documentation on [functions and scripts](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Functions-and-Scripts.html#Functions-and-Scripts).

Comment: @horchler I tried pretty much everything there before, but I will go over everything again to check that I have not done anything wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to call `file1` in `file2`:

```
function file2()
    variable = file1();
    variable2 = variable*2; % do you want to return variable2 as the output of file2?
endfunction
```

**EDIT**

If your function returns more than one variable, the process is exactly the same, i.e.:

```
function [x,y,z] = file1()
    x = 1;
    y = 2;
    z = 3;
endfunction

function file2()
    [x,y,z] = file1();
    variable2 = 2*(x+y+z); % do you want to return variable2 as the output of file2?
endfunction
```

Comment: In my actual program I have more than one variable. How could I make it so that I can call file1() and have the output be more than one variable?